# The unalias in the Mysql Backup script

Tags: linux, scripting

Here's the script to back up Mysql database.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=minime.sql.`date +%F`
DBSERVER=127.0.0.1
DATABASE=wordpress
USER=root
PASS=789789

unalias rm  2> /dev/null
rm $FILE  2> /dev/null
rm $FILE.gz  2> /dev/null
mysqldump --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASS $DATABASE > $FILE
gzip $FILE
echo "$FILE.gz was created"
ls -l $FILE.gz
```

Although in the command, they said 3 of these lines used to remove previous version of the file, i still don't understand why we have to unalias rm and redirect stderr to /dev/null.

```
unalias rm  2> /dev/null
rm $FILE  2> /dev/null
rm $FILE.gz  2> /dev/null
```

Comment: FYI, you may want to look at this script I wrote many years ago: http://serverfault.com/a/54477/12539.  I'm not 100% sure if that version of the script still works with current mysql but it should be easy enough to change a few of the `mysqldump` options until it does.  Anyway, the script dumps the schema separately from the data, making it easy to just recreate the same table structure on a different machine if needed.  or to just re-import the data without deleting and re-creating all the tables.  I'd probably do the 30-day expire at the end of the script very differently today too.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the script author wanted to make absolutely sure that the `rm` command was not modified by any existing `alias` statement.

The author could also have accomplished this by using the absolute path `/bin/rm` instead of `rm`.

```
RM="/bin/rm"
$RM $FILE ...
```

Why the author chose to redirect `rm` to STDERR eludes me, since the `rm -f` option does the same thing.